# Uploading a file to Google Shared Drive via Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use google spreadsheets to upload files to a certain folder on a Shared Drive. I've found this code online and it didn't actually work to start with but I played with it and it would still not initiate the upload.

The code I used came from [this website](https://blackstormdesign.com/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-through-google-sheets/).
I've modified the upload function:

```
folderId = 'my folder ID'

driveId = 'my shared drive ID'
function onOpen(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach", menuEntries);
}

//the upload script
function upload(obj) {
var metadata = {
      "parents": [{
        "id": folderId,
        "kind": "drive#parentReference"
}],
    "teamDriveId": driveId };
  var optionalParams = {
    "supportsAllDrives": true
      };
  
file = Drive.Files.insert(metadata, optionalParams);

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var File_name = file.getName()
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + File_name + '")'
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
  var cell = selection.getCurrentCell()
  cell.setFormula(value)
  return {
    fileId: file.getId(),
    mimeType: file.getMimeType(),
    fileName: file.getName(),
  };
}
```

Comment: In your script, `obj` of `upload(obj)` is not used. What is `obj`?

Comment: I know. I think there is something wrong with the original code I used as a reference. In there it was:

`var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folder_Id).createFile(obj.upload);`

This one does not work as I need to use the Advanced `Drive` feature instead of the `Drive.App`

Comment: This one does not work as I need to use the Advanced `Drive` feature instead of the `Drive.App` as I need to upload to a shared drive. So, yeah, that actually got me confused, maybe I should remove the `obj` from the function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries. What I'm trying to do is: Click on a cell on a spreadsheet that will trigger an upload menu (choose file>upload) then return a link after upload is complete  the file should be stored in a specific folder on a "team drive" or now called a "shared drive".. Is it a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

I think the obj refers to the type of file you are uploading maybe, you can review the proper code in this documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart

Just make sure to select "Java."

Here is the example in that KB:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```